# postgres add user error

Tags: mac-osx, postgresql

I am trying to add a new user as follows:

```
sudo -u postgres createuser -D -A -P onemoreadmin
```

I am entering the password right.

Then, I get the following error:

```
createuser: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Answer (score 1):

try with below code

```
sudo -u postgres createuser -D -A -P onemoreadmin -h localhost
```

-h --> hostname